# Javascript prototype, use of this when calling via different functions

Tags: javascript, function, this, prototype

I'm using multiple prototypes to manage some complex situations and I'm having trouble with the use of 'this'. I'm not 100% certain how to describe as I'm not familiar with the correct terminology, but I'll have a go.

Function X has a variable that points to a function within function Y. This method within function Y wishes to access a variable that is within the scope of the function Y, but when I use this, it refers to function X.

I've created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/metalskin/qkp2x/) with an example, using prototypes and so on (as that is the scenario that I find myself in). However the code is short, so I'll include it below:

```
var Abc = function(options) {
    alert('2');
    options = options || {};
    this.myVar = options.myVar || 'Abc.myVar';
};
Abc.prototype = {
    onEvent: function() {
        alert('myVar: ' + this.myVar);
    }
};
var Xyz = function(options) {
    alert('3');
    options = options || {};
    this.listenFn = options.listenFn || function() {
        alert('x');
    };
    this.myVar = options.myVar || 'Xyz.myVar';
};
Xyz.prototype = {
    execute: function() {
        alert('4');
        this.listenFn();
    }
};
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('1');
    var a = new Abc();
    var x = new Xyz({listenFn: a.onEvent});

    x.execute();
});
```

I've put in alerts in sequence of the code execution. So:

1. is the start of the document ready.
2. is the creation of the Abc instance.
3. is the creation of the Xyz instance, where the onEvent function for the instance of Abc is assigned to the listenFn for Xyz.
4. is inside the point where execute on Zyz has been called which in turn calls the onEvent of Xyz and it displays the value for this.myVar.

The problem I have is that 'this' is referring to the Xyz instance when inside a method on Abc. I need to be able to set/get the value of myVar for the instance of Xyz. I suspect I could do something messy with creating a function that is passed into the new Xyz statement and thus have the instance of Abc passed back to itself, but unfortunately this is not possible with what I am working with (also not very elegant).

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

Here's the answer to your question

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('1');
    var a = new Abc();
    var x = new Xyz({listenFn: a.onEvent.bind(a) }); // <------- bind

    x.execute();
});
```

Using bind like this will pre-set the `this` value inside of a.onEvent to be `a`.  Just note that IE8 does not support `bind`, but you can easily add a shim [from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

The other way to do this would be to say:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('1');
    var a = new Abc();
    var x = new Xyz({listenFn: function() { a.onEvent() }); 

    x.execute();
});
```

---

Without diving too deeply into your code, I'll just say this: figuring out the value of `this` in JavaScript is quite easy; it all depends on the manner in which the function is **called**.

- If you have `x.foo()`, then, no matter what*, `this` will be equal to `x` inside of foo.
- If you have `foo()`, then, no matter what*, `this` will be the global object, or undefined in strict mode inside of foo.
- If you say `new foo()` then `this` will be a new object whose prototype will be set to `foo.prototype`
- If you say `foo.call(a)`, there `this` will be `a`* inside of foo, but that doesn't really apply here.

*The one exception being that if you had declared foo as

```
var foo = function() { }.bind(obj);
```

then you've pre-bound `this` to be `obj` for all calls of foo, and will override the rules above.

Comment: So is there an easy way to access myVar for the Abc instance when executing a function on the Abc prorotype that was called from a function on the Zyz prorotype? I suspect I will have to include the Abc instance as a param, but was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: @Metalskin - not sure - I'm not seeing that situation in your code.  If you have `Abc.prototype.foo = function() { var X = new Xyz(); }` then of course you could say X.myVar.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Not quite Adam. The problem is that foo1.prototype has a 'listener' function. for a given instance of foo1, the method is assigned to foo2. Foo2 calls this method, so when the method defined in foo1.prorotype is executing, this refers to the instance of foo2, not foo1. I need to know how to access the vars scoped to foo1 in this case. If you run the JSFiddle you will see that the value of this.myVar is for the foo2 instance, not the foo1 instance.

Comment: Thanks Adam, that works. It's neater than the alternative and stops me from having to change Xyz. I was hoping to only change the internals of the function itself, but this will work. Again, thanks :-) I'll be using the second approach, it makes more sense and now I understand why people do that!